# What type of isomers are the following two compounds?

Tags: molecular-structure, isomers, cis-trans-isomerism

What type of isomers are the following two compounds?They do not seem to be geometrical isomers as the methyl groups at terminal position are not in same plane as such.Are they conformers?

[image]

Comment: Believe it or not, they are _enantiomers_. Oh, and you don't normally draw them like that, because like you said, those methyls are out of plane.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more elaborately if you have time?Thanks. @IvanNeretin

Comment: @IvanNeretin I did'nt draw them :-P!

Comment: Then these pictures are meaningless and don't represent anything. Or, if we put it another way, they are poorly drawn pictures of the same compound (like in @julien's answer), which, BTW, exists as a pair of enantiomers, but the pictures don't tell you which is which.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Oh well I think I understood why they are enantiomers!

Comment: Related: [Why are allenes chiral?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/6477/7951) and [How are the Cahn-Ingold-Prelog rules applied to chiral molecules without a stereogenic carbon center? i.e biphenyls and allenes](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/18839/7951)

Comment: It is easier to visualise if you draw, for example,  the methyl and the hydrogen on the left  in the plane of the paper, then the methyl and hydrogen on the right, are at right angles to this and so in and out of the plane.

Comment: @Sanc Are you sure, though, that those questions are unrelated? Perhaps they're very relevant and you just stopped someone from helping you.

Comment: @TIPS I'm sorry.